# ${\lim_{z \to ia} \cos z}$ and ${\lim_{z \to ia} \Re (e^{iz})}$, are they equal or not?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Say I have two limits, $\displaystyle{\lim_{z \to ia} \cos z}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{z \to ia} \Re (e^{iz})}$ for some real constant $a > 0$. Basically $\cos z = \Re(e^{iz})$ for sure, but the first limit should lead to $\cos ia$ while the second should give $\Re(e^{-a}) = e^{-a}$. Now $\cos ia \neq e^{-a}$. Why is it like that?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the limit, but that the identity $\cos z = \Re(e^{iz})$ holds only for *real* numbers $z$:
$$
 \Re(e^{iz}) = \frac 12 \left( e^{iz} + e^{-i \bar z}\right) \\
 \cos(z) = \frac 12 \left( e^{iz} + e^{-i z}\right) \\
$$
are equal if and only if
$$
 e^{-i \bar z} = e^{-i z} \iff z = \bar z  \iff z \in \Bbb R \, .
$$